# Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object error to show the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with CodeIgniter. This is the message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/read.php
>
> Line Number: 89

I have a model like this:

```php
var $news = 'news';

function read($id)
    {
        $this->db->join('category', 'category.id_category = news.id_category');
        $this->db->join('editor', 'editor.id_editor = news.id_editor');
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->news, array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row();
    }
```

This is my controller:

```php
 ...
$data['news'] = $this->Newsmodel->read($id);
$this->load->view('read', $data);
```

And this is my view:

```php
...
       <div class="news">
            <?php  echo $news->title; ?>
        </div>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Because `$news->title` does not exists. Try `var_dump($news);` and see what is in `$news`

Comment: yes i agree with @User016

Comment: it doesn't work. I put it into my controller:
$data['news'] = $this->Newsmodel->read($id);
var_dump($data['news']);
$this->load->view('news', $data);

Oh, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `$this->db->select('title);` in your model's **read()** function's first line.

then replace **return $query->row();** this from Your model with the below

```
return $query->result();
```

then replace **echo $news->title;** this in Your views with the below:-

```
echo $news[0]->title;
```